# bad array values from __construct()

Tags: php, facebook

The purpose of this code is just separate the config data. If i use the `$config` array directly in the example.php all works properly. However in the code below i get different values.

facebook.php

```
 <?php
    class Facebook extends AppController{
        public  function __construct() {
            $config = array();
            $config['appId'] = '400xxx6'; //YOUR_APP_ID
            $config['secret'] = 'f70f01e76xxx7e'; //YOUR_APP_SECRET
            $config['cookie'] = false;
            return $config;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

example.php

```
<?php 
App::import('Config', 'Facebook');

$a = new Facebook();
var_dump($a);
?>
```

Why `$var_dump($a);` return  something like this?

```
object(Facebook)[50]
  protected 'appId' => null
  protected 'apiSecret' => null
  protected 'user' => null
  protected 'signedRequest' => null
  protected 'state' => string 'e4ac55f1xxx87a88' (length=32)
  protected 'accessToken' => null
  protected 'fileUploadSupport' => boolean false
```

What I want is the original array. What is the mistake?

```
array
  'appId' => string '400xxx6' (length=15)
  'secret' => string 'f70f01e76xxx7e' (length=32)
  'cookie' => boolean false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that when you do:

```
$a = new Facebook();
```

the class being instantiated is not the one you created. I believe you use Facebook PHP SDK, and their class name is also `Facebook`. You have conflicting class names.

Change your class name for something else like `FacebookConfig` and you'll be fine.

Also, it would make more sense to store your array in the class instance, something like:

```
class FacebookConfig extends AppController{

    public $config = array();

    public function __construct() {
        $this->config = array();
        $this->config['appId'] = '400xxx6'; //YOUR_APP_ID
        $this->config['secret'] = 'f70f01e76xxx7e'; //YOUR_APP_SECRET
        $this->config['cookie'] = false;
    }
}
```